# How to create mongoDb schema for subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have document like below. Here `peoples` contains array of ObjectId which points to user collection. And `contribution` field contains as many number of subdocument as `peoples` field. Length is variable like if some group has 2 ObjectId in `people` then `contribution` will have 2 sub document. I need to create mongoDb schema for this, please tell me schema for this.

```
{
   name: "person name",
   _id: ObjectId(""),
   creater: ObjectId("1"), //referencing to user collection
   peoples: [ObjectId("1"), ObjectId("2"),...upto n], //all referencing to user table
   contribution: {
                  ObjectId("1"):{
                                paid: 1200,
                                due: 1000,
                                prevDue: 200,
                                Advance: 0
                               },
                  ObjectId("2"):{
                                paid: 1200,
                                due: 1000,
                                prevDue: 200,
                                Advance: 0
                               },
                  //upto end of lists in peoples array
                 },
  estimated: 30000,
  collected: 15379,
  left: 14721
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to reference the nested schema in your main `schema`. For eg:

```js
let user = new Schema({
  name: String
})

let schema = new Schema({
  followers: [user]
})
```

In the `followers` field of `schema`, you just referenced the `user` schema. Whenever this kind of reference is done, the types of `nested schema` get injected into the reference point.

Comment: Sorry that I rejected your recent [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26343671). I was (clearly) confused between the legitimate "Pacman" that your referred to and another system, which *is* called "PackMan."

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation. Notice that I defined `contribution` property as an array of `peopleContributionSchema`. This makes the collection data easier to be accessed as you can loop for items in that array. The way you implemented is not flexible as `ObjectId` is a property of contribution, so you would need to know before hand the number of people in the contribution.

```
var peopleContributionSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    paid: Number,
    due: Number,
    prevDue: Number,
    advance: Number
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, // not necessary to define. Mongoose will add by default
    name: String,
    creater: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    peoples: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    contribution: [peopleContributionSchema],
    estimated: Number,
    collected: Number,
    left: Number
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it what you want to do but you can't iteration a schema object like an 'n' no of series. 
 An object schema in MongoDB is like key-value pair in JSON Object, you can't iterate it like a loop. Instead, the approach to do that is, define two different schemas and assign one schema in an array to use it in another schema as a subschema. 
Follow the below-mentioned code:

```
{
       name: "person name",
       _id: ObjectId(""),
       creater: ObjectId[1], 
       peoples: [ObjectId[0], ObjectId[1],...upto n-1],
       ObjectId: [
                   {
                     paid: 1200,
                     due: 1000,
                     prevDue: 200,
                     Advance: 0
                   },
                   {
                     paid: 1200,
                     due: 1000,
                     prevDue: 200,
                     Advance: 0
                   }
                 ],
      estimated: 30000,
      collected: 15379,
      left: 14721
}
```